# Gradient of Frobenius inner product involving a homogeneous function

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, tensors

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a differentiable function. I want to take the gradient of the Frobenius inner product between $X$ and $f(X)$ with respect to $X$. That is, I want to differentiate the scalar function
\begin{align}
\phi(X)&= X : f(X)=  \text{tr}(X^T f(X))  
\end{align}
with respect to $X$. I think the product rule applies (right?), so we get
\begin{align}
\partial \phi(X) &= \partial X : f(X) + X : \partial f(X).
\end{align}
I have the following questions:

1. If $f$ happens to satisfy
   \begin{align}
   \partial f(X):X = f(X):\partial X,
   \tag{$*$}\label{eq:1}
   \end{align}
   am I allowed to write
   \begin{align}\frac{\partial \phi(X)}{\partial X} = 2 f(X) \tag{$**$}\label{eq:2} \  ?
   \end{align}
2. We say that $f$ is homogeneous if $f(cX)=cf(X)$ for all $c\ge 0$. If $n=1$,
   then $f$ can be seen as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. In this particular case, the homogeneity condition implies \eqref{eq:1} (right?). Does it also work for $n>1$?

**EDIT:** In the vector case $(n=1)$, the directional derivative of $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with respect to $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and also evaluated at $x$ is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot x &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon x) - f(x)}{\epsilon} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+\epsilon) f(x) - f(x)}{\epsilon} \\
&= f(x),
\end{align}
and I believe \eqref{eq:1} must follow from that, but I'm struggling to make this point precise too.

Comment: What's the argument for the vector case (homogeneity impies *?

Comment: I answered it as an edit in the question. Thank you.

Comment: There is a way to use Euler's Theorem to evaluate the Taylor series for $\partial f,\,$ but at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06526) shows, it's not particularly simple.

Comment: thank you very much @greg. I'll take a look at it.